# how do I make it so the devices do not automatically connect to each other using bluetooth

Tags: ios, swift, bluetooth, multiplayer

I am exploring the world of bluetooth for a class project that I am working on.

https://www.ralfebert.de/tutorials/ios-swift-multipeer-connectivity/

I have been using the above tutorial for a bluetooth/wifi connection and I have learned to send data between two devices. Everything is working great!

My question is: how do I make it so the devices do not automatically connect to each other using bluetooth. I would like for you to be able to click a button which opens a menu in which you can pick devices for bluetooth connection based on names. I was unable to find any online tutorials and was hoping someone here could help me.

I am looking for the ability to pop up this menu: 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/4hP3h.png

Comment: Anyone able to assist?  :)

Comment: Sahil, are you still needing an answer or did you figure it out? I have a pretty good idea of how to do what you're looking for but if you've sorted it out, won't bother. Let me know. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Since your question is very specific about the example article, I'll answer directly on what you can change on that code. Note, I did not write that code originally and I only made minimal changes to make it work for what you asked for.

Here is the link:
https://www.ralfebert.de/tutorials/ios-swift-multipeer-connectivity/

That code does indeed automatically "connect" the devices together without any input from the user. The reason why the devices connect is because in the delegate `MCNearbyServiceBrowserDelegate`, the `browser(browser:foundPeer:withDiscoveryInfo)` is performing an `invitePeer` method call right away.

```
// This is what is causing the immediate connection to the devices
browser.invitePeer(peerID, to: self.session, withContext: nil, timeout: 10)
```

By the way, the purpose of the `browser(browser:foundPeer:withDiscoveryInfo)` delegate method is indeed to let you know that new peers are available. It's up to you to connect to them if you wish!

To do what you want (which is to connect manually by selecting a device to connect to), instead of connecting automatically, you need to keep track of the peers you've found, communicate that to your view and let the view show a list, or whatever other UI you wish to show.

Let's do that.

First, inside `protocol ColorServiceManagerDelegate {}`:

```
// Add a protocol method to communicate the "found" peers has changed.
// We will need to implement this in the view and will do so later on!
func foundPeersChanged(manager: ColorServiceManager, peersFound: [String])
```

Then, inside the main class `class ColorServiceManager : NSObject {}`, let's add 2 properties to keep track of found peers:

```
// Add two class properties to keep track of the peers we've found
fileprivate var peerNames: [String] = []
fileprivate var peerObjects: [MCPeerID] = []
```

Next, in `MCNearbyServiceBrowserDelegate` change `foundPeer` and `lostPeer` to keep track of the peers list.

```
func browser(_ browser: MCNearbyServiceBrowser, foundPeer peerID: MCPeerID, withDiscoveryInfo info: [String : String]?) {
  NSLog("%@", "foundPeer: \(peerID)")

  // Here, we found a peer.

  // Add the list of found peers
  if !self.peerNames.contains(peerID.displayName) {
    self.peerNames.append(peerID.displayName)
  }
  if !self.peerObjects.contains(peerID) {
    self.peerObjects.append(peerID)
  }

  // Fire off our delegate to let implementers know there's been a change in found peers
  self.delegate?.foundPeersChanged(manager: self, peersFound: self.peerNames.sorted())

}

func browser(_ browser: MCNearbyServiceBrowser, lostPeer peerID: MCPeerID) {
  NSLog("%@", "lostPeer: \(peerID)")

  // Here, we note that we've lost a peer.

  // Of course, we also need to remove peers from the set of found peers when we lose a peer.
  self.peerNames = self.peerNames.filter { (peerName) -> Bool in
    peerName != peerID.displayName
  }
  self.peerObjects = self.peerObjects.filter({ (peerToTest) -> Bool in
    peerToTest != peerID
  })

  // Fire off our delegate to let implementers know there's been a change in found peers
  self.delegate?.foundPeersChanged(manager: self, peersFound: self.peerNames.sorted())

}
```

Then, you're going to need a way to **connect** to a peer, so in the class `ColorServiceManager`, right after the `init()` method, add a new method:

```
func invite(peer peerName: String) {
  NSLog("%@", "peerName: \(peerName)")
  // Find the peerName in peerNames array and if found, invite to connect
  if let indexOfPeer = self.peerNames.index(of: peerName) {
    // Found it, so invite the peer to connect
    let peerToInvite = self.peerObjects[indexOfPeer]
    NSLog("%@", "invitePeer: \(peerToInvite)")
    self.serviceBrowser.invitePeer(peerToInvite, to: self.session, withContext: nil, timeout: 10)
  }
}
```

Over in your view controller, you need to implement a tableView and related methods as well as the new method in the delegate.

Go to Interface Builder and add a Table View to the view, then link it to your view controller as usual:

```
@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
```

Make sure you add a prototype cell to the table view in IB. Set the cell to **Style: Basic** and set the **Identifier** to `foundPeerCell`.

Also, add a property to your view controller to back up the tableView:

```
var foundPeers: [String] = []
```

Then, add the following to `extension ColorSwitchViewController: ColorServiceManagerDelegate {}`

```
func foundPeersChanged(manager: ColorServiceManager, peersFound: [String]) {
  // The list of found peers has changed, so we update our tableView
  NSLog("Current list of peers:\n\(peersFound)")
  self.foundPeers = peersFound
  DispatchQueue.main.async {
    self.tableView.reloadData()
  }
}
```

Finally, add the code needed to manage the tableView:

```
/**
 UITableView Data Source
 */
extension ColorSwitchViewController: UITableViewDataSource {

  func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
  }

  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return foundPeers.count
  }

  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "foundPeerCell")!
    cell.textLabel?.text = foundPeers[indexPath.row]
    return cell
  }

}

/**
 UITableView Delegate
 */
extension ColorSwitchViewController: UITableViewDelegate {

  // handle tap on a row
  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    // Send back the invite to the peer.
    colorService.invite(peer: foundPeers[indexPath.row])
    // De-select the row
    tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
  }

}
```

Note that the `tableView(tableView:didSelectRowAt)` is where we connect back to the `ColorServiceManager` and invite the peer that the user has tapped.

Note, I did not add a lot of error handling, so you'll want to harden this code, etc.

An edited version of the project is available here:
https://github.com/ericwastaken/Bluetooth_ConnectedColors/tree/stack_overflow_answer_manual_device_connection

Good luck!